Avoiding deploy-time exception when the bean is not found for injection
I have this issue: I'm deploying an application (.ear) to WebLogic/CDI and I have this in one of my classes:
@Inject
@MyAnnotation
private IMyStuff stuff;

Of course, if there is no bean with this @MyAnnotation found at deploy-time, an exception is thrown by the container and the application is not deployed. How can I avoid this ? I want to have "stuff" as null and the application deployed without exceptions.

You cannot have an unsatisfied dependency at deployment time with CDI.
All injection points have to resolvable.
As a side note, this also applies to ambiguous dependencies - cases where more than one bean fits given injection point.
There is only one case in which a bean may be null and that's if the bean is @Dependent and there is a producer for it [conditionally] returning null. But even in this case, the bean exists for that given injection point, it just so happens that it may return null (it is a super rare case to be honest).
If you are OK with the bean not being there, do not explicitly state an injection point for it and instead use programmatic lookup (i.e. @Inject Instance<Object> interface) where you can check if such bean exists before requesting it. You can also use CDI.current() and perform the same from there.
However, note that this shift the responsibility for destruction of any @Dependent scoped beans resolved this way onto you as a user as they are not bound to any other bean. You can use the Instance interface to dispose of such bean as well.
Last but not least, I'd warn against excessive usage of the pattern you are requesting as CDI is designed to work on a known-set of beans and the validation is actually a good safe-guard to let you know if you have all the beans that your application potentially requests.

thank you, I understand; the pattern I'm talking about has nothing excessive in it, I simply need a backup or a default when a bean is not found; throwing an exception at deploy-time is not very useful, since it's impossible to somehow react to that from your code perspective; this is really a big minus for WebLogic

The concept of default beans is not baked into CDI although some frameworks already have it (Quarkus does, anyway). It might be worth raising a feature request under specification.
Only other way I can think of to react to this is via CDI extensions where you'd have to provide some mock bean impls if you detect no such bean was found in the container. But that's pretty complex.
